# onBackKeyDown get specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I want to use the backkey @ android phones to go back to some specific page.
My code(JS):

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
    currentId = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
    if(currentId == "#swipediv"){
    $.mobile.changePage("#home", "slide", false, true);
    }
    else{
    history.go(-1);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="home">
      <div data-role="header"><h1>Test</h1></div>
        <div data-role="content">
          <p>Home</p>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="swipediv">
        <div data-role="page" data-theme="a" id="1">
            <div data-role="header"><h1>1</h1></div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>1</p>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

What's wrong ? Any suggestions?

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly added the backbutton listener like this?

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Register the event listener
        document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    }
```

If yes then you check for the pageid `currentId == "#swipediv"` should be used without `#`
Like this

```
currentId == "swipediv"
```